# Error array, i cant get out the information - in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i got a big trouble which i couldnt solve, this is a very weird problem :S i use the next code:

```
for( $m = 0; $m < sizeof( $jugadores ) ; $m++ )
{   
            $juga_q = "INSERT INTO jugadores VALUES($jugadores[$m][1],$nom_equipo,'',$jugadores[$m][4]);";
            $result = mysql_query( $juga_q );
            echo $juga_q."<br>";
}
```

i got information in the array which i want to insert into my data base, for that i dump my query in $juga_q variable which i use in the insert into, but the query doesnt execute and i make an echo to check whats failing and got the next:

```
 INSERT INTO jugadores VALUES(Array[1],Aston Villa,'',Array[4]);
```

when i make a echo of the array out of this query i got no problems, thats why im getting crazy with that and hope u could help me.

Thanks forward!!

Answer (score 1):

try to concatenate it,

```
$juga_q = "INSERT INTO jugadores VALUES(". $jugadores[$m][1].",$nom_equipo,'',".$jugadores[$m][4].");";
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

When using array accessors in strings, you need to wrap them in brackets.

Instead of `"VALUES ($jugadores[$m][1],..."`, try using `"VALUES ({$jugadores[$m][1]},..."`.

Comment: Thanks to all , specially helmbert , ur solution made it!! thanks so much!! thanks also to JW for the security hint

Comment: Glad to help. Please feel free to mark the answer that you found most helpful as accepted. ;)